# Multi-user Snippet Manager

Tags: collaboration, code-snippets

Currently, we're using a wiki at work to share insights, tips and information. But somehow, people aren't sharing snippets that way. It's probably too inconvenient to write and too difficult to find snippets there.

So, is there a multi-user/collaborative snippets manager around? Something like [Snippely](http://code.google.com/p/snippely/). (Has anyone tried Snippely in multi-user mode?)

- Since we're all on the same site, it would probably be best if it used mapped network drives or ODBC instead of its own server process.
- Oh, and it has to support Unicode and let us choose any truetype font. We're using the hideous APL language, which uses [special characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language)#APL_symbols_and_keyboard_layout).
- It would be nice if it didn't cost money, so I wouldn't have to convince management to pay for it as well as the other developers to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pastebin** is a common solution to this.  Just install somewhere on your network, then paste snippets. http://pastebin.com/

Works well when trying to debug a piece of code, or stack trace also.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Improving on Pastebin with better Unicode support and syntax highlighting is one option.

Comment: I see that Pastebin has been improved recently, and supports Unicode better.

Answer (score 0):

There's Snip-it pro ( http://www.snipitpro.com ), I looked at it a while back, and the interface seemed to be pretty horrible. It's 40 bucks / seat, which is not too bad. Last time I was looking for a tool like that I found nothing at all, and I found that it's very hard to get my co-workers to start using snippet libraries - everybody is happy to google it or search their old codebases. These days I use Evernote for all of my own snippeting needs.